# View contents of fulfilled/failed courier contract

Tags: eve-online

My latest courier contract failed and I want to find out which items exactly I shipped there. It was a very long list and I don't remember the details. I can open the contract, but I don't see any details about the freight there, just the route and all the other stuff.

Is there a way to see which items where part of a fulfilled or failed courier contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not possible, though CCP are looking at UI changes, so, it could be implemented in the near future.